# OpenSIPs - It failed to connect domain address to the OpenSIPs server

Tags: linux, opensips

I am trying to build an Android application that uses OpenSips server.

I've installed OpenSIPs server, but it failed to connect my domain address (Custom IP address) to the OpenSIPs server.

Somehow local address is working fine.

Here are the errors.

ERROR:core:udp_init: bind(5, 0x7f5522350c74, 16) on 192.168.1.117: Cannot assign requested address

ERROR:core:tcp_init: bind(7, 0x7f6466d7ee3c, 16) on 192.168.1.117:5061 : Cannot assign requested address

It would be great if you can give me some advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

OpenSIPs wasn't bind to public IP address on Linux

go to /etc/sysctl.conf and add below line

```
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind = 1
```

and run on the command line

```
sysctl -p
```

It will work now..

Answer (score 1):

Do you have anything else listening on those ports (5060 and 5061)? Any other SIP software maybe. Try to look through all the existing bindings:

```
netstat -putln
```